# Why my web traffic is redirected via IP 10.0.0.11 address on my Mac?

Tags: linux, macos, proxy, http-proxy, malware-detection

I know nothing about networking. so I need serious help here. I was on a Zoom call with my mentor and we were talking about the difference between HTTP, HTTP1, and HTTP2. Then he noticed that even websites which are supposed to use HTTP1 all of them were showing as if they are using HTTP2.

He mentioned possible problems are:

- I'm using VPN
- or my web traffic is redirected via a Proxy server. (which I'm not since I work from home via my wifi provided to me via fiber optic cable)

I suspect that there is some kind of proxy malware on my laptop. Can anybody tell me how can i detect any possible malware and find out in general what is wrong? (if anything is wrong at all)

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The range from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255 is one of the private IP Ranges and as you are using wifi its normally assigned by your wifi-router/accesspoint to your computer using dhcp.

But seriously, a professor who thinks he is capable talking about http(x) should know the very basics of the protocol stack. If he doesn't know such simple things, you better get someone better.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I checked on my other laptop with PopOs version of the Linux distro. It has the same IP address assigned. 

I guess I made the wrong impression about my mentor. He is a nice guy. He pointed out the problem and I'm trying to solve it.

Comment: two devices with the same IP is definitive a error... maybe you are not using dhcp but manual addressing? Or both devices are configured to habe the same MAC ID (should be unique)... Never the less, sounds like a problem. Maybe you should start checking the config and logs of the router / AP first.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to educate myself more. Will follow your recommendation.